# Hat Dash Leaderboard links to unused network site profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

For some reason, my picture on the [Hat Dash Leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard) is linking to my profile `workplace.stackexchange.com`. This is a network I joined today to earn a hat, but I don't need it to be the one that gets linked on the leaderboard. How is this set, and should it be set to my main profile on `stackoverflow.com` instead?

Comment: Probably it just link to the most recent site.

Comment: Maybe, but I've just participated on meta with this question and it hasn't switched...

Comment: I believe Shadow Wizard means the site on which you most recently earned a hat, not simply where you last participated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intended behavior was to link to the site profile where you have the most hats earned. There was a bug in that, and instead it was just randomly selecting one of your site profiles where you earned hats. This has been fixed.

> earn a place at top
> link to a site where you shine
> just keep on dashing